# When deleting SMS, they don't get deleted

Tags: sms, command, gsm, at-command

I connected a GSM/GPRS-modem to my microcontroller and everything works fine.
When I want to delete all messages in the ME storage, I should use this command:

```
AT+CMGD=1,4

->OK
```

The deleteflag '4' indicates that I want to delete all messages and flag '1' is overridden. However, when I check if the storage is empty, I get:

```
AT+CPMS?
+CPMS: 8,100,8,100,8,100
```

Indicating that the memory is still occupied and no message got deleted.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give some more information about this modem? Does some of the identification commands (
AT+CGMI,
AT+CGMM,
AT+CGMR,
AT+CGSN,
AT+CIMI,
AT+GMI,
AT+GMM,
AT+GMR,
ATI0,
ATI1,
ATI2,
ATI3,
...
) provide any useful info?

Answer (score 2):

I use the [CMGD command](http://www.developershome.com/sms/cmgdCommand.asp) to delete messages.

As far as I can see the [CMGR command](http://www.developershome.com/sms/cmgrCommand.asp) is used to read messages and not delete them.

### Edit (since you were using the CMGD command)

It is possible that your modem doesn't support multiple parameters to the CMGD command - my Siemens modem does not (or if it does it doesn't list it in the AT command set document). Instead of deleting all the messages in a single command I do a CMGL to get read messages, parse the results to get the index and them delete them one at a time using CMGD. If you do find another way I'd be interested.

Use the AT+CMGD=? command to find valid values of the parameters.

### Edit (since you verified the modem supports CMGD with two parameters

I don't know what the problem is.
I did notice that your CPMS command gives different results to mine, example of mine:

```
AT+CPMS?
+CPMS: "SM",10,10,"MT",12,35,"MT",12,35
```

Yours doesn't have any storage memory string. I'm guessing the command you actually did was:

```
AT+CPMS="ME"
```

When you switch to ME storage and do a CMGL command does it list the undeleted messages?

Comment: Well, using AT+CMGD=? returns

0-255, 0-4

Meaning that it should support deleting all messages. That's also correct according to the documentation (we're talking about a Sagem HiLo btw). 

I have a strong hunch that it deletes all the messages from the SM storage (SIM), although I set my preferences to 'ME'. Yet, when I send this command:

AT+CMGD=1

it deletes the message on index 1 of the ME as it should.

What's your wisdom on this?

Comment: Hehe, sharp-eyed.
That's because I was typing that response out of my head (working on different computers, that's why).
Thus the response (and I verified this now) is:

+CPMS: "ME",8,100,"ME",8,100,"ME",8,100

Comment: *shrug* I have no further ideas that could help, good luck solving the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set memory to ME using "AT+CPMS="ME"" and then retry your delete command with flag=4. I guess it will work. It not then run "AT+CSAS" to save the earlier setting and the retry delete. I could not test it as there is no SMS in my ME storage area. Let me know if it worked.